# How to fix the "The requested URL was not found on this server" apache2 + django + ec2?

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, apache2

I'm doing the deploy of a website built with django and python2.7  on an EC2 instance and using apache2.

I've being following some tutorials and none of them worked for me. I currently installed the apache, configured it to see the project and even configured the permissions.

The project directory:

```
    |
    |-ubuntu
       |
       |- jendalma
              |--apps
              |--media
              |--promotions
              |--sellerlogin
              |--templates
              |--frobshop
                    |
                    |---frobshop
                            |
                            |---setting.py
                            |---wsgi.py
                            |---urls.py
                            |---static
```

000-default.conf   - apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin <jendalma@gmail.com>
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/jendalmaShop/frobshop/frobshop/wsgi.py
        Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/jendalmaShop/frobshop/frobshop/static/
        Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/jendalmaShop/frobshop/media/
        <Location "/static/">
                Options -Indexes
                        AllowOverride none
                        Require all granted
        </Location>
        <Location "/media/">
                AllowOverride none
                Require all granted
        </Location>
        <Location "/">
                AllowOverride none
                Require all granted
        </Location>

        <Directory "/home/ubuntu/jendalmaShop/frobshop/frobshop/wsgi.py">
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

urls:

```
js_info_dict = {
    'packages': ('stores',),
}

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),

    # Stores extension
    url(r'^stores/', stores_app.urls),
    url(r'^dashboard/stores/', dashboard_app.urls),

    # PayPal extension
    url(r'^checkout/paypal/', include('paypal.express.urls')),

    # Datacash extension
    url(r'^dashboard/datacash/', datacash_app.urls),
    url(r'^dashboard/login/$', DashAccountAuthView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^dashboard/register/$', DashAccountRegistrationView.as_view(), name='register'),
    url(r'^dashboard/methods/shipping/$', methods),
    url(r'^dashboard/methods/shipping/change/$', change_method),
    url(r'^currencies/', include('currencies.urls')),
    url(r'^customer/', include('sellerlogin.urls')),
    url(r'', application.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ]


admin.site.site_header = "Jendalma Express Admin"
admin.site.site_title = "Jendalma Express Admin"
admin.site.index_title = "Welcome to Jendalma Express"
```

The error received when I try to access the url:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at <> to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Comment: Change debug to True in your settings.py and then tell us what you see.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I changed debug to True and it shows the same error I showed you. However, if I look the apache log, it appears the error: ImportError: No module named frobshop.setting

Comment: That makes me think its a server configuration issue. You might want to repost the issue with the "ImportError: No module named frobshop.setting" in the title. Unfortunately I don't have a lot of deployment experience and none with Apache, so I can't help otherwise.